Python Unittest - Exception not raised
I'm currently struggling with python unittest and since I'm trying hard for almost 2 weeks on that issue I need help when trying to test the exception block. Below you see an example function and it's respective example test:
-> Source code:
def create_df() -> pd.DataFrame:
    
    # Building dataframe
    try:
        return pd.DataFrame(data = {
            'id' : [1, 2, 3],
            'country' : ['Germany', 'France', 'United Kingdom'],
            'capital' : ['Berlin', 'Paris', 'London'],
            'currency' : ['EUR', 'EUR', 'GBP'],
            'random_no' : [random.randint(1, 10), random.randint(1, 10), random.randint(1, 10)]
        }).reset_index(drop = True)
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error occurred in creating testing dataframe: {repr(e)} - Trace: {traceback.print_exc()}')

-> Test Code:
class TestCreateDF(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('app.random.randint', side_effect = Exception('Random Error'))
    def test_create_df_raise_exception(self, mock_randint):
    
        # Act        
        with self.assertRaises(Exception) as context:
            create_df()
            
        # Assertion
        self.assertEqual(str(context.exception), 'Random Error')

I always do get the error message as below pasted:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/usr/Desktop/02_Testing/UnitTest-Learning/src/app.py", line 19, in create_df
    'random_no' : [random.randint(1, 10), random.randint(1, 10), random.randint(1, 10)]
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/usr/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/unittest/mock.py", line 1134, in __call__
    return self._mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/usr/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/unittest/mock.py", line 1138, in _mock_call
    return self._execute_mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/usr/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/unittest/mock.py", line 1193, in _execute_mock_call
    raise effect
Exception: Random Error
Error occurred in creating testing dataframe: Exception('Random Error') - Trace: None
F.
======================================================================
FAIL: test_create_df_raise_exception (test_app.TestCreateDF.test_create_df_raise_exception)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/usr/.pyenv/versions/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/unittest/mock.py", line 1387, in patched
    return func(*newargs, **newkeywargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/usr/Desktop/02_Testing/UnitTest-Learning/test/test_app.py", line 44, in test_create_df_raise_exception
    with self.assertRaises(Exception) as context:
AssertionError: Exception not raised

But I clearly raised the exception with
with self.assertRaises(Exception) as context:

It's really frustrating actually. Thanks in advance!

Uhm, but your create_df does not raise anything - it silences all exceptions and just prints something.

So I do need to add the keyword "raise" after my print statement? @STerliakov?

That would be one of your options, yes: bare raise will re-raise the handled exception, that's convenient if you only want to log it before failing.

Thanks to @STerliakov I've made the necessary modifications by adding raise after my print statement and it worked. It's a little bit unusual since I never used it before, but since I'm learning unit testing I think I need to use it. Thanks @STerliakov

A solution (not far from that suggested by @STerliakov) is the following.
Modification to the production code
In the production code add a return instruction in the block which manages the Exception as showed in the following snippet of code:
def create_df() -> pd.DataFrame:
    # Building dataframe
    try:
        # --- your code ---

    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error occurred in creating testing dataframe: {repr(e)} - Trace: {traceback.print_exc()}')
        # HERE ADD THE return INSTRUCTION
        return str(e)

The previous code avoids the Exception raising inside the except block suggested by the @STerliakov's comment.
Note I have saved your production code in a file called prod.py.
Test code
The test method becomes:
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from prod import create_df

class TestCreateDF(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('app.random.randint', side_effect=Exception('Random Error'))
    def test_create_df_raise_exception(self, mock_randint):
        # Act
        result = create_df()
        # Assertion
        self.assertEqual(result, 'Random Error')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

Output of test execution
The output of the execution of the test in my system is the following:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/production/script/prod.py", line 13, in create_df
    'random_no': [random.randint(1, 10), random.randint(1, 10), random.randint(1, 10)]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/mock.py", line 939, in __call__
    return _mock_self._mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/mock.py", line 999, in _mock_call
    raise effect
Exception: Random Error
Error occurred in creating testing dataframe: Exception('Random Error',) - Trace: None


Ran 1 test in 0.002s

OK

If I remove the instruction:
print(f'Error occurred in creating testing dataframe: {repr(e)} - Trace: {traceback.print_exc()}')

from your production code the output becomes clearer:
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK

The last easy output shows that, when the Exception is raised by the execution of the function randint(), it is correctly caught by the production code and this is what you need verify by the test.
